# Python: Using a dictionary to mutate all items in a list

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

I want use a dictionary to change the string into integers but I'm note really sure how.   For example:

```
secret = raw_input(enter the secret code)
list(code)
dictionary = {a:1, b:2, c:3,d:4,e:5,f:6,g:7,h:8,i:9,#etc.}
encryptedSecret = dictionary(code)
return encryptedSecret
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over each element:

```
encrypted = ''

for character in secret:
    encrypted += dictionary[character]
```

Or more concisely:

```
encrypted = map(dictionary.get, secret)
```